# Llamar a funcion angularjs desde javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

En una aplicación que estoy haciendo, se me solicito poder abrir la aplicación desde el navegador. Instale el plugin `cordova-plugin-customurlscheme` para definir esto y funciona a la perfección.

Desde el navegador, recibo ciertos valores cuando se abre la aplicación, intente definir la funcion `handleOpenURL` dentro del controlador , pero recibo el error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: handleOpenURL is not defined
>       at :1:1

Estuve investigando de este error y se soluciona agregandolo en el archivo `index.html` como un `<script>` quedando asi :

```
<script>
    handleOpenURL = function (url) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert(url);
        },0);
    };
</script>
```

Sin embargo, al recibir la URL me gustaria obtener los parametros, por ejemplo yo recibo el alert

```
miapp://?parametro=valor
```

Y tambien me gustaria manejar eventos de `angularjs` como redireccionar o enviar un alert `ionic`, sin embargo desconozco si se puede acceder a una funcion de un controlador fuera de ella, si esto pasa a ser mala practica o alguna posible solucion.

Comment: Prueba [esto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) para recibir los parámetros de la url

Comment: gracias @aldanux!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actualmente estoy utilizando el servicio que necesitas en una App Ionic, te recomiendo que lo hagas de la siguiente manera:

1 - Instala el siguiente plugin y modifica testapp por el nombre que quieras:

```
    cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin.git \
 --variable URL_SCHEME=testapp
```

2 - En tu app.js inserta este fragmento de código:

```
.run(['$state', '$window',
    function($state, $window) {
        $window.addEventListener('LaunchUrl', function(event) {
            // gets page name from url
            var page =/.*:[/]{2}([^?]*)[?]?(.*)/.exec(event.detail.url)[1];
            // redirects to page specified in url
            $state.go('app.'+ page, {});
        });
    }
]);

function handleOpenURL(url) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        var event = new CustomEvent('LaunchUrl', {detail: {'url': url}});
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }, 0);
}
```

3 - Añade un estado en tu router provider:

```
.state('app.page, {
    url: '/page,
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/yourtempalte.html',
            controller: 'PageCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

4 - Desde tu web app llama a window.location = 'testapp://parametro' y debería funcionar.

Ya nos cuentas, saludos¡

Comment: Hola David, gracias por responder. La verdad es que segui tus consejos pero me queda solo una duda, es necesario definir un router provider? Yo lo que hice fue crear un controlador, sin un template y funciono correctamente!

Comment: Hola amigo, no es necesario, era solo en caso de que al entrar en la App desde una web vaya a alguna vista especial, puedes quitarlo y poner el código que quieras, por ejemplo el alert que tu tienes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! me haz salvado :D

Comment: Me alegro mucho de que te haya funcionado¡ aquí estamos para ayudar, saludos¡